# Ho to use GroupBy and Windows function on the same query in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to combine GroupBy and Window functions in the same query, to avoid the need for a self-join.

Using this table as example:

```sql
WITH Purchase AS
 (
  SELECT '2023/06/14' as purchase_date, "kale" as product, 10 as purchases, 'John' as purchaser
  UNION ALL SELECT '2023/06/14', "kale", 15, 'Tom'
  UNION ALL SELECT '2023/06/14', "banana", 2, 'John'
  UNION ALL SELECT '2023/06/14', "banana", 4, 'Tom'
  UNION ALL SELECT '2023/06/15', "kale", 9, 'John'
  UNION ALL SELECT '2023/06/15', "kale",15, 'Tom'
  UNION ALL SELECT '2023/06/15', "banana", 6, 'John'
  UNION ALL SELECT '2023/06/15', "banana", 6, 'Tom'
)
SELECT * FROM Purchase
```

```
| purchase_date | product | purchase | purchaser |
| ------------- | ------- | -------- | --------- |
| 2023/06/14    | kale    | 10       | John      |
| 2023/06/14    | kale    | 15       | Tom       |
| 2023/06/14    | banana  | 2        | John      |
| 2023/06/14    | banana  | 4        | Tom       |
| 2023/06/15    | kale    | 9        | John      |
| 2023/06/15    | kale    | 15       | Tom       |
| 2023/06/15    | banana  | 6        | John      |
| 2023/06/15    | banana  | 6        | Tom       |
```

I need for each day and for each product the sum of the purchase and the sum of all the purchases of that day.

The first part is easy using `group by`

```
SELECT
  purchase_date,
  product,
  SUM(purchases) as sum_of_product
FROM Purchase
GROUP BY purchase_date, product
```

```
| purchase_date | product | sum_of_purchase |
| ------------- | ------- | --------------- |
| 2023/06/14    | kale    | 25              |
| 2023/06/14    | banana  | 6               |
| 2023/06/15    | kale    | 24              |
| 2023/06/15    | banana  | 12              |
```

When trying to combine that with a window function, I cannot make it work:

```
SELECT
  purchase_date,
  product,
  SUM(purchases) as sum_of_product,
  SUM(purchases) OVER(PARTITION BY purchase_date)
FROM Purchase
GROUP BY purchase_date, product
```

The error is:

> SELECT list expression references column purchases which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [16:7]

Any help?
thanks

Comment: try this one `SUM(SUM(purchases)) OVER (PARTITION BY purchase_date) as sum_of_day`  instead.

Comment: thanks! that really helped! Sadly I cannot upvote a comment!